# What is PERMANOVA and when to use it instead of multivariate ANOVA?

Tags: anova, manova, ecology

I have some data on spatial and temporal variation of macrobenthic species. I tried to test the difference between seasons and sites, and noticed that PERMANOVA is recommended in the literature. (But I think the better way is to use non-metric multidimensional scaling.)

What is PERMANOVA? How does it work? How should I interpret the results of this test? What is the permutation in PERMANOVA? When to use it instead of MANOVA?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?  I'm sure a simple web search will give you a summary of `PERMANOVA`.

Comment: I think we'll need more information about your situation, your data & your goals to be able to answer this. Can you say more?

Comment: @gung: But perhaps the question is simply "what is PERMANOVA?" and when it is advantageous to use it (that's how I understand OP); if so, then it's a legitimate question here even without any description of the situation, data and goals. +1. I thought I should mention it.

Comment: [Anderson 2001](http://entocert.net/PDF/MUVE/6_NewMethod_MANOVA1_2.pdf); [Anderson & Walsh 2013](http://izt.ciens.ucv.ve/ecologia/Archivos/ECO_POB%202013/ECOPO2_2013/Anderson%20y%20Walsh%202013.pdf)